# Error with a progress dialog

Tags: java, android

What is wrong with the progress dialog?
The java file:

```
 public class Start_Screen extends Menu_Activity {


List<Bitmap> lbmp;
List<String> ltitles;
List<String> ldesc;
Custom_Adapter adapter;
ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_screen);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setTitle("Downloading...");
    pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
    pd.setCancelable(false);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.soundslist);

    lbmp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ltitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ldesc = new ArrayList<String>();

    new Download().execute();

    adapter = new Custom_Adapter(this, lbmp, ltitles);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}


public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "picsite.comze.com/?json=1";
        F JSONparser = new F();
        JSONObject picsite = JSONparser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try {
            JSONArray posts = picsite.getJSONArray("posts");
            for(int i=0;i<posts.length();i++){
                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString("title");
                ltitles.add(title);

                JSONArray photos = post.getJSONArray("attachments");
                JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(0);
                String URL = photo.getString("url");

                URL downURL = new URL(URL);
                HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection)downURL.openConnection();
                connect.setDoOutput(true);
                connect.connect();
                InputStream is = connect.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                lbmp.add(bmp);

                String desc = photo.getString("description");
                ldesc.add(desc);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;    
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }


}
}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319): Activity com.tendarius.sounds.Start_Screen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{411a6c08 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tendarius.sounds.Start_Screen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{411a6c08 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at com.tendarius.sounds.Start_Screen$Download.onPreExecute(Start_Screen.java:126)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at com.tendarius.sounds.Start_Screen.onCreate(Start_Screen.java:49)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-22 06:39:24.835: E/WindowManager(1319):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try dismissing process dialog in onDestroy() method

Comment: paste your code for async task also

Answer (score 0):

You should create your dialog before showing it.

For example:

pd.create().show();
instead

pd.show();

Also in your onPostExecute check if pd!=null then do pd.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

check that activity is exist or not by checking isfinishing() in your asynctask

```
  if(!(Activity) context).isFinishing()){
     dialog.show();
       }

 if(!(Activity) context).isFinishing()){
     dialog.cancel();
       }
```